# Get current logged in user under 3.1, re: remove "Howdy"

Tags: admin, jquery, users

I use this in `functions.php` to change "*howdy*" to "*Logged in as....*" But now under 3.1 I get "*Logged in as Your Profile*" rather than "*Logged in as `<current user>`"*

What needs to be changed so that "user" below (commented below as `//get current user?)` returns the current user in 3.1?

```
if (is_admin()) {
    add_action('init', 'better_howdy_h');
    add_action('admin_footer', 'better_howdy_f');

    function better_howdy_h() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }

    function better_howdy_f() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    var user = jQuery('#user_info p a:first').text();
    var howdy = jQuery('#user_info p')
        .html()
        .replace(/<.+>/ig,'')
        .replace(/\ \|\n/ig,'');
    jQuery('#user_info p')
        .html(
            jQuery('#user_info p')
                .html()
                .replace(user,'My Profile')
        .replace(howdy,'Logged in as ' + user + ' | ') //get current user?
                .replace('!',' |')
                .replace('| |','|')
        );
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Don't you have it already in the `user` variable you extracted from the text?

Comment: I don't know; that's the complete function I am using. I don't see in the first place where `user` is grabbed.

Comment: Just some lines above: `var user = jQuery('#user_info p a:first').text();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why fiddle around with jQuery when you could just run a filter on `gettext` to specifically target that text? Perhaps you simply don't know you can do that, so here's how..

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_howdy_text', 10, 2 );
function change_howdy_text( $translation, $original ) {
    if( 'Howdy, %1$s' == $original )
        $translation = 'Logged in as %1$s';
    return $translation;
}
```

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Ah, very smart. I was using the original function as I stole it from a plugin called "Better Howdy." Didn't realize there was an easier way. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what the %1$s is please? I carn't seem to find anything on wordpress about it.

Comment: They are placeholders for variable data used in translation strings, see [I18n_for_WordPress_Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Comment: .. And Mark, you're welcome mate... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (is_admin()) {
    add_action('init', 'better_howdy_h');
    add_action('admin_footer', 'better_howdy_f');

    function better_howdy_h() {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }

    function better_howdy_f() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var user = jQuery('#user_info div p').text();
        user = user.substr(7);
        jQuery('#user_info div p').html("Logged in as "+user);
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php 
    } 
}
```